# What should be the double weights and bias for NOT perceptron?

Tags: neural-network, logical-operators, perceptron

```
import pandas as pd

# TODO: Set weight1, weight2, and bias
weight1 = -2.5
weight2 = -1.5
bias = 1.0

# DON'T CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW
# Inputs and outputs
test_inputs = [(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]
correct_outputs = [True, False, True, False]
outputs = []

# Generate and check output
for test_input, correct_output in zip(test_inputs, correct_outputs):
    linear_combination = weight1 * test_input[0] + weight2 * test_input[1] + bias
    output = int(linear_combination >= 0)
    is_correct_string = 'Yes' if output == correct_output else 'No'
    outputs.append([test_input[0], test_input[1], linear_combination, output, is_correct_string])

# Print output
num_wrong = len([output[4] for output in outputs if output[4] == 'No'])
output_frame = pd.DataFrame(outputs, columns=['Input 1', '  Input 2', '  Linear Combination', '  Activation Output', '  Is Correct'])
if not num_wrong:
    print('Nice!  You got it all correct.\n')
else:
    print('You got {} wrong.  Keep trying!\n'.format(num_wrong))
print(output_frame.to_string(index=False))
```

What should be the weights and bias above?
confused since its a double weight perceptron, I tried many values but atleast 1 is wrong in the end

Answer (score 1):

NOT operation can be used in one of the inputs. Assuming that it takes into account only the second input and ignores the first input, an example of a line that separates the two classes can be seen below (x=0.5).

To find the weights, let's use the equation w1x1+w2x2+b=0. Since the first input is ignored, that means that w1=0. The equation now becomes w2x2+b=0 or x2=-b/w2=constant. Assuming that the decision boundary is x=0.5, we can try to set w2=-1 or w2=1. For those values, b has to be 0.5 and -0.5 respectively. For the example above, we should keep the values w2=-1 and b=0.5.

[Decision boundary of a NOT perceptron](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUEV0.png)